# get iscsi ip from initiator name

Tags: linux-kernel, iscsi

In Linux how can I get iscsi target IP if I know the initiatorname either programmatically or by reading /sys filesystem. That is Without using iscsiadm or reading /etc/iscsi/node/* links.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
initiator ip: /sys/class/scsi_host/$host/device/iscsi_host/${host}/ipaddress 
target    ip: /sys/class/scsi_host/$host/device/session${s}/connection*/iscsi_connection/connection*/address
```

where $host the scsi host name